# Javascript passing values to multi dimensional objects error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to figure out why this is happening, without results, so far.
I am using bootstrap and Jquery in a page. After the following code, inside an anonymous function, trying to set global scope object values(mats):

```
var matData = {
m1: {name: "Mat-1 name", color: '#d8ccb6'},
m2: {name: "Mat-2 name", color: '#502e35'},
m3: {name: "Mat-3 name", color:'#303742'},
m4: {name: "Mat-4 name",color: '#2e3136'},
m5: {name:"Mat-5 name",color: '#47513e'}
};

var mats={
    m0: {name: "none",price: 0,color: "transparent"},
    m1: {name: "none",price: 0,color: "transparent"},
    m2: {name: "none",price: 0,color: "transparent"}
    };  
var temp1 = matData[matDD]["name"]; //"apple"
        var temp2 = matData[matDD]["color"];// "red"
```

after these lines:

```
mats[matsK].name= temp1;
mats[matsK].color = temp2;
```

object mats will be:

```
mats={
        m0: {name: "apple",price: 0,color: "red"},
        m1: {name: "apple",price: 0,color: "red"},
        m2: {name: "apple",price: 0,color: "red"}
        };
```

the whole object, every index, not just the matsK will contain temp1 and temp2 values.Its not inside a loop.

I have been debugging it for 10 hours, nothing works.
Why does the following code sets every element of the object to temp1 and temp2?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please update your question  with more info, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question

Comment: Do you need a loop? Is that your question?

Comment: Please be sure to clearly state what your question is. If possible, end your post with a clear, concise, one sentence question so that other users have a good understanding of what needs to be addressed.

Comment: What values do matDD and matsK have?

Comment: mattDD = "m1";
matK ="m1"